# properties file in Web project

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, web, properties

I have all my programming code packaged in a jar file. This Jar file i will be placing in my dynamic web project to execute the logic in a jar.

But jar file has some logic which reads a .properties file to get some configuration values.

When i run my web project for the logic i get a error `java.io.FileNotFoundException: conf\conf.properties (The system cannot find the path specified)`

```
WebContent
|__WEB-INF
|___conf
|____conf.properties
|___lib
|_____myJar.jar
|__classes
```

I have following code for reading the properties file.

```
String propFileName = "conf/conf.properties"; 
Properties prop = new Properties();
prop.load(getClass().getResourceAsStream(propFileName));
```

Any suggestion to resolve this issue plz.

I have also tried with

```
String propFileName = "conf/conf.properties";
File file = new File(propFileName);
Properties prop = new Properties();
FileInputStream fileInput = new FileInputStream(file);
prop.load(fileInput);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your approach based on [`Class#getResourceAsStream(name)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getResourceAsStream-java.lang.String-) will only work if and only if your file is accessible from the `ClassLoader` of your calling class and here  what you have directly under `WEB-INF` is not accessible, you should move `conf/conf.properties` in `WEB-INF/classes` instead and use `/conf/conf.properties` as resource name to make it get the file from the root not from the package of your calling class.

Comment: I missed to mention one more thing then. My jar is having filter implementation. And in my web project i have made a configuration which will invoke this filter  based on URL pattern. So in my project i don't see any  `WEB-INF/classes`

Comment: please clarify that in your initial question. I don't understand why you cannot see `WEB-INF/classes` as it is accessible from the webapp `ClassLoader` which contains `jar` files in 'WEB-INF/lib' and the directory `WEB-INF/classes`

Comment: Forgive me.. I just misunderstood your comments initially. And now it worked.. Thank you :)

Comment: I am just curious why my second approach didn't work? In that i had placed the properties file inside a jar also. And when i tried it in a simple java pgm with main method it had worked.

Comment: Which approach the one with `FileInputStream` ?

Comment: Yes one with `FileInputStream`

Comment: because If you provide a relative path, it will relative to the user directory which is not `WEB-INF`

Comment: I have tried it by keeping the `conf` folder as mentioned in my 1st post. In that case it should have picked it from `conf` folder insied `WEB-INF` right

Comment: if you want to know what is the user directory simply execute this `System.out.println(System.getProperty("user.dir"))`

Answer (score 0):

To read a properties file web-inf folder in servlet project do the followoing

```
ServletContext.getResourceAsStream("WEB-INF/conf/conf.properties")
```

Comment: I am reading the properties file in a class which is there inside a `myJar.jar`